# Add PrimeNG into Angular2 app using Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, primeng

I am attempting to load PrimeNG into my Webpack bundled Angular2 app.

First I did an npm install:

```
npm install primeng --save
npm install primeui --save
```

This added the following two lines to my package.json:

```
+    "primeng": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
+    "primeui": "^4.1.12",
```

Next, as shown in this [github commit](https://github.com/cagataycivici/angular2-webpack-starter/commit/d0f7c6bdbdb6128660e337ff147f686215eda303#diff-f737fedb5357468044db2dbe98eb0218R118) from angular2-webpack-starter, I add an import to `venders.ts`:

```
import 'script!primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.js';
```

It seems like `script!` is some kind of special thing that my webpack doesn't know how to do.  I am getting this:

```
ERROR in ./src/vendor.ts
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'script' in /SomeDir/src
 @ ./src/vendor.ts 14:0-47
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
    chunk    {0} index.html 570 kB
         + 4 hidden modules
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

I am not sure if this is problem or not.  My app still loads...

Continuing, I add the following two imports to my AppComponent:

```
import {TabView} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {TabPanel} from 'primeng/primeng';
```

This generates the following additional warnings:

```
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
[default] Checking started in a separate process...
[default] /.../node_modules/primeng/components/breadcrumb/breadcrumb.d.ts:3:24 
    Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
[default] /.../someDir/node_modules/primeng/components/contextmenu/contextmenu.d.ts:4:24 
    Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
[default] /.../someDir/node_modules/primeng/components/megamenu/megamenu.d.ts:4:24 
    Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
[default] /.../someDir/node_modules/primeng/components/menu/menu.d.ts:4:24 
    Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
[default] /.../someDir/node_modules/primeng/components/menubar/menubar.d.ts:4:24 
    Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
[default] /.../someDir/node_modules/primeng/components/panelmenu/panelmenu.d.ts:3:24 
    Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
[default] /.../someDir/node_modules/primeng/components/slidemenu/slidemenu.d.ts:4:24 
    Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
[default] /.../someDir/node_modules/primeng/components/splitbutton/splitbutton.d.ts:4:24 
    Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
[default] /.../someDir/node_modules/primeng/components/tabmenu/tabmenu.d.ts:3:24 
    Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
[default] /.../someDir/node_modules/primeng/components/tieredmenu/tieredmenu.d.ts:5:24 
    Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
```

Questions:

- How can I add PrimeNg to an Angular2 project using Webpack?
- Why isn't my `import 'script!'...` working?
- Why can't primeng find angular?

Comment: What's version of angular2 do you use? Could you please show us your `package.json`?

Comment: Primeng requires RC version of angular2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like I had two independent issues, both of them related to missing things in my package.json

#### Issue 1

> It seems like script! is some kind of special thing that my webpack
>   doesn't know how to do. I am getting this:
>
> ```
> ERROR in ./src/vendor.ts
> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'script' in /SomeDir/src
>  @ ./src/vendor.ts 14:0-47
> Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
>     chunk    {0} index.html 570 kB
>          + 4 hidden modules
> webpack: bundle is now VALID.
> ```

#### Issue 2

The problem here was that I was missing the `script-loader`.  I resolved this by doing an:

```
npm install script-loader --save
```

See - [Using Loaders](http://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html)

> This generates the following additional warnings:
>
> webpack: bundle is now VALID. [default] Checking started in a separate
>   process... [default]
>   /.../node_modules/primeng/components/breadcrumb/breadcrumb.d.ts:3:24 
>       Cannot find module '@angular/router'. [default] /.../someDir/node_modules/primeng/components/contextmenu/contextmenu.d.ts:4:24
>
> ```
> Cannot find module '@angular/router'. [default] /.../someDir/node_modules/primeng/components/megamenu/megamenu.d.ts:4:24
>
> Cannot find module '@angular/router'. [default] /.../someDir/node_modules/primeng/components/menu/menu.d.ts:4:24 
> Cannot find module '@angular/router'. [default] /.../someDir/node_modules/primeng/components/menubar/menubar.d.ts:4:24
>
> Cannot find module '@angular/router'. [default] /.../someDir/node_modules/primeng/components/panelmenu/panelmenu.d.ts:3:24
>
> Cannot find module '@angular/router'. [default] /.../someDir/node_modules/primeng/components/slidemenu/slidemenu.d.ts:4:24
>
> Cannot find module '@angular/router'. [default] /.../someDir/node_modules/primeng/components/splitbutton/splitbutton.d.ts:4:24
>
> Cannot find module '@angular/router'. [default] /.../someDir/node_modules/primeng/components/tabmenu/tabmenu.d.ts:3:24
>
> Cannot find module '@angular/router'. [default] /.../someDir/node_modules/primeng/components/tieredmenu/tieredmenu.d.ts:5:24
>
> Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
> ```

Adding the router to my `package.json` resolved this issue:

```
"@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
```